# case_when & %in%

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `%in%` in `case_when()`, however it doesn't work as it does in general in R. Below is an example. Can someone guide what's wrong with this implementation?

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("abc A", "xyz B", "jkl C"), text = c("my name is abc A", 
"my name is xyz B", "my name is jkl C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

x <- c("ABC","B","C")

df %>% mutate(flag=case_when(name %in% x~TRUE, TRUE~FALSE))
```

**Output**

```
 name             text  flag
abc A my name is abc A FALSE
xyz B my name is xyz B FALSE
jkl C my name is jkl C FALSE
```

**Expected output**

```
 name             text  flag
abc A my name is abc A TRUE
xyz B my name is xyz B TRUE
jkl C my name is jkl C TRUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected output. The string `"abc A"` is not found in the vector `c("ABC","B","C")`, and neither is `"xyz B"` or `"jkl C"`.

Are you perhaps trying to find string matches? Then you should use `str_detect` rather than `%in%`

```r
df %>% mutate(flag=case_when(stringr::str_detect(name, x)~TRUE, TRUE~FALSE))
#>    name             text  flag
#> 1 abc A my name is abc A FALSE
#> 2 xyz B my name is xyz B  TRUE
#> 3 jkl C my name is jkl C  TRUE
```

Note that if you only have two options, `TRUE` or `FALSE` for an output, you don't need `case_when` at all.`

```r
df %>% mutate(flag = stringr::str_detect(name, x))
#>    name             text  flag
#> 1 abc A my name is abc A FALSE
#> 2 xyz B my name is xyz B  TRUE
#> 3 jkl C my name is jkl C  TRUE
```

Also notice that case 1 should be `FALSE`, because `"abc"` does not match `"ABC"`. If you do not care about case, you can use `grepl`, as AndS describes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to collapse x to be a pattern. try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(flag=grepl(paste(x, collapse = "|"), name, ignore.case = T))
#>    name             text flag
#> 1 abc A my name is abc A TRUE
#> 2 xyz B my name is xyz B TRUE
#> 3 jkl C my name is jkl C TRUE
```